# open file directory from JSF application

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm working with JSF Primefaces using JACOB to upload excel files into your path directory. What I want to do is give the user a link that points where that file is located in its path.

The path directory is: C:\HUT\result

I am currently using this in my .xhtml :

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
template="/template/ui.xhtml">

<ui:define name="body">
    <h:form>
        <br>
        <h:outputText value="Tier 1 Standard: #{trialWaterfall.value1}" />
        </br>

    </h:form>

    <a href="file:///C:/HUT/result/">Login page</a>


</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: I think this kind of href will try to open something in the client machine, not in the server.

Comment: to export as excel, use apache poi